# filter based on presence of entry in sub-object

Tags: json, jq

For this:

```
{
    "item-1": {
        "sub-item-1": {
            "prop_1": 0,
            "prop_2": "bar"
        },
        "sub-item-2": {
            "prop_1": 0,
            "prop_2": "bar",
            "prop_3": "OK"
        }
    },
    "item-2": {
        "sub-item-1": {
            "prop_3": "OK"
        }
    }
}
```

I want a jq filter that gives me the same structure, but only the sub-objects that have the "prop_3" entry:

```
{
    "item-1": {
        "sub-item-2": {
            "prop_1": 0,
            "prop_2": "bar",
            "prop_3": "OK"
        }
    },
    "item-2": {
        "sub-item-1": {
            "prop_3": "OK"
        }
    }
}
```

I can filter the top level using the following:

```
jq 'with_entries(select([.key] | inside("item-1", "item-2")))
```

But can't figure out how to extend this further down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just.. `select` them?

```
.[][] |= select(has("prop_3"))
```